# Change column names using custom function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one data frame where the column names look something like this

```
Clicks_alpha0_beta0
Clicks_alpha0_beta1
Clicks_alpha0_beta2
Clicks_alpha1_beta1
Clicks_alpha1_beta2
Clicks_alpha1_beta3
...
Impressions_alpha0_beta0
Impressions_alpha0_beta1
Impressions_alpha0_beta2
Impressions_alpha1_beta1
Impressions_alpha1_beta2
Impressions_alpha1_beta3
...
Clicks_3adstock_alpha0_beta0
Clicks_3adstock_alpha0_beta1
Clicks_3adstock_alpha0_beta2
Clicks_3adstock_alpha1_beta1
Clicks_3adstock_alpha1_beta2
Clicks_3adstock_alpha1_beta3
...
Impressions_3adstock_alpha0_beta0
Impressions_3adstock_alpha0_beta1
Impressions_3adstock_alpha0_beta2
Impressions_3adstock_alpha1_beta1
Impressions_3adstock_alpha1_beta2
Impressions_3adstock_alpha1_beta3
...
Clicks_4adstock_alpha0_beta0
Clicks_4adstock_alpha0_beta1
Clicks_4adstock_alpha0_beta2
Clicks_4adstock_alpha1_beta1
Clicks_4adstock_alpha1_beta2
Clicks_4adstock_alpha1_beta3
...
```

also, I have a custom function to split the column names from the right side into two parts.
the second part will be "alphaX_betaY" and the first part will be the remaining left side. for e.g.

```
"Clicks_4adstock_alpha1_beta3" will be converted into ['Clicks_4adstock',  'alpha1_beta3']
"Impressions_alpha0_beta2" will be converted into ['Impressions', 'alpha0_beta2']
```

I want to make these two parts of the column as multilevel columns.
How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html) with [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns.str.extract(r'(.*)_(alpha.*)'))
```

EDIT: If need split by `separator` from right side, e.g. here by second `_` use custom function:

```
def splitter(c, sep, pos):
    head, *body = c.rsplit(sep, maxsplit=pos)
    return (head, sep.join(body))
    
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: splitter(x, '_', 2))
```

EDIT1:

If need split only if exist `alpha` or `beta` in columns name use:

```
def splitter(c, sep, pos):
    if 'alpha' or 'beta' in c:
        head, *body = c.rsplit(sep, maxsplit=2)
        return (head, sep.join(body))
    else:
        return c
```

Comment: Hi, this looks good but I want to split the column name through a delimiter and its position. It is always not a case that the second part will start from alpha itself.

Comment: @GovindBanura - Can you check edited answer?

Comment: There are other columns as well in the data frame like "click_3adstock". This function splits those columns as well and creates a multiindex. which should be avoided. we can take a position from the last 2 words in one part and the remaining in the other.

Comment: @GovindBanura - yes, my solution split by `rsplit` - splitting from back. And by second `_`. Do you need something else?

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom function (the function should take a string as input and return a list/tuple of strings) with [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) and [`pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip(*df.columns.map(custom_func)))
```

Or [`pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(tuple, df.columns.map(custom_func)))
```

*NB. `map(tuple, …)` is only required if the custom function can return lists, if it already returns tuples `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns.map(custom_func))` is sufficient.*

##### original answer

If `_alpha` can always be found you can use [`Index.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with a regex with a lookahead:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(r'_(?=alpha)', expand=True)
```

Now the columns are:

```
print(df.columns)

MultiIndex([(              'Clicks', 'alpha0_beta0'),
            (              'Clicks', 'alpha0_beta1'),
            (              'Clicks', 'alpha0_beta2'),
            (              'Clicks', 'alpha1_beta1'),
            (              'Clicks', 'alpha1_beta2'),
            (              'Clicks', 'alpha1_beta3'),
            (         'Impressions', 'alpha0_beta0'),
            (         'Impressions', 'alpha0_beta1'),
            (         'Impressions', 'alpha0_beta2'),
            (         'Impressions', 'alpha1_beta1'),
            (         'Impressions', 'alpha1_beta2'),
            (         'Impressions', 'alpha1_beta3'),
            (     'Clicks_3adstock', 'alpha0_beta0'),
            (     'Clicks_3adstock', 'alpha0_beta1'),
            (     'Clicks_3adstock', 'alpha0_beta2'),
            (     'Clicks_3adstock', 'alpha1_beta1'),
            (     'Clicks_3adstock', 'alpha1_beta2'),
            (     'Clicks_3adstock', 'alpha1_beta3'),
            ('Impressions_3adstock', 'alpha0_beta0'),
            ('Impressions_3adstock', 'alpha0_beta1'),
            ('Impressions_3adstock', 'alpha0_beta2'),
            ('Impressions_3adstock', 'alpha1_beta1'),
            ('Impressions_3adstock', 'alpha1_beta2'),
            ('Impressions_3adstock', 'alpha1_beta3'),
            (     'Clicks_4adstock', 'alpha0_beta0'),
            (     'Clicks_4adstock', 'alpha0_beta1'),
            (     'Clicks_4adstock', 'alpha0_beta2'),
            (     'Clicks_4adstock', 'alpha1_beta1'),
            (     'Clicks_4adstock', 'alpha1_beta2'),
            (     'Clicks_4adstock', 'alpha1_beta3')],
           )
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4BB4bD/1)

Comment: Hi, this looks good but I want to split the column name through a delimiter and its position. It is always not a case that the second part will start from alpha itself.

Comment: @Govind sure, see update to use a custom function

Comment: @Govind can you explain what you have if not _alpha? There's a chance you can still avoid the custom function

Comment: yes, beta can come first and alpha can be the second one. 
The custom function worked but there is an issue with it. 
if there are other columns in the data frame which have only single or double words like "Click", "Impressions", or "Click_3adstocks", these column names should be in the top level of the multi-index, currently they are coming in the bottom level of the multi-index.

Comment: @Govind The question seems more complex than originally explained, you must provide all details in the question. Or close this one and open a follow-up. To swap the levels either do it in your function (return the reverse) or use `swaplevel`

Comment: Regarding the alpha/beta/… you can modify my original answer to use `df.columns.str.split(r'_(?=alpha|beta)', expand=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DataFrame as df

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'Clicks_alpha0_beta0': [1, 2], 'Clicks_alpha0_beta1': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def split_column_name(column_name):
    parts = column_name.split('_')
    alpha_beta = parts[1].split('alpha')[1] + '_beta' + parts[2].split('beta')[1]
    return (parts[0], alpha_beta)

df.columns = df.columns.map(split_column_name)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns, names=['Clicks', 'Alpha_Beta'])

print(df)
```

Comment: let me rephrase the question for better understanding